# List of MAC addresses for 10 machines

Tags: windows-7, script, powershell, shell-script

I need to list of MAC addresses for a 10 computers having Windows 7 installed on them. These are named in a series like training1 - training10.

There IP addresses are on DHCP mode and update every week.

Any ideas on how do I script this on Windows? I know BASH scripting but windows powershell is new for me.

Comment: Try this PS: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b780c4e4-e986-40a3-9296-65caadd31211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
# An array of server names
$servers = 'comp1','comp2','comp3','comp4';
Get-WmiObject -computer $servers -class win32_networkadapter | 
    Where-Object AdapterType -eq 'Ethernet 802.3' | 
    Format-Table -auto __SERVER,Caption,ServiceName,AdapterType, MacAddress
```

with the result being something like (MAC addresses deliberately hidden):

```
__SERVER Description                                   ServiceName AdapterType    MacAddress
-------- -----------                                   ----------- -----------    ----------
COMP1    Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter netvsc      Ethernet 802.3 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
COMP2    Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter netvsc      Ethernet 802.3 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
COMP3    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller            RTL8167     Ethernet 802.3 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
COMP3    Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Adapter      VMSMP       Ethernet 802.3 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
COMP4    Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller            RTL8167     Ethernet 802.3 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Note:

1. Some computers can have multiple NICs, and thus multiple MAC addresses.
2. Not all NICs are physical. (Hyper-V virtualisation above.)
3. When working from the command line I would use PSH aliases and positional parameters:

   ```
   gwmi -comp 'comp1','comp2','comp3','comp4' win32_networkadapter | ? AdapterType -eq 'Ethernet 802.3' | ft -auto __SERVER,Caption,ServiceName,AdapterType, MacAddress
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There's a cmdlet for that:

[`Get-NetAdapter -Physical`](https://web.archive.org/web/20160911123858/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867.aspx) will give you information on your local interfaces.

If you add the `-CimSession` parameter (`Get-NetAdapter -Physical -CimSession`), you can connect to a server by its `ComputerName`.

You end up with: `Get-NetAdapter -Physical -CimSession "ComputerName, ComputerName"`, where you can also fill `ComputerName` with a variable containing the names of the servers you will be working with. Separate multiple computer names with a `,`.

You will find the PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment by searching for `powershell_ise.exe` at the root of your *Boot Volume (usually C:)* in Windows Explorer :). You'll probably want to right-click and run it as Administrator ;).

Why should you use CIM? Some reasons to attempt to persuade you:

> goals for new CIM Cmdlets
>
> - Rich PowerShell experience. Make CIM a first class citizen of PS, addressing usability concerns and user feedback for WMI and WsMan Cmdlets.
> - Standard compliance. With so much focus on standards, our goal is to make PowerShell the best platform for managing Windows and Non-Windows. New CIM Cmdlets should be able to manage any CIM + WsMan compliant endpoint, including Windows.
> - Support for down-level machines. We understand that there are more down-level servers in a datacenter than there would be Windows Server 2012 for some time to come. We want to make sure same set of Cmdlets can be used to manage down-level Windows as well.

You can read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets.aspx)!

***One more thing***: You'll need to be using Windows PowerShell 3.0 or above for this to work; to learn how to upgrade your version of Windows PowerShell from Windows 7 click [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311225905/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx).

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark my answer as useful. If you're getting into PowerShell you might be interested in reading [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Learn-Windows-PowerShell-Month-Lunches/dp/1617291080/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1403876534&sr=8-1&keywords=a+month+of+lunches+with+powershell). Happy travels!